# В чем разница объектного кода от байт-кода

Tags: c#, .net

Не могу никак понять,если в .Net используется cil код то он байт-код или объектный,если объектный то есть и такой процесс компоновки или же он и с байт-кодом присутствует

Comment: Просто выражение "байт-код" устоялось. "Байт-код" = "Промежуточный код"

Comment: В C# нет ярко выделенного процесса компоновки. Компилятор проходится по файлам, собирая типы в отдельную сборку. Тут нет классической C компоновки.

Comment: Еще прочитал на википедии ,что динамическая библиотека это файл с машинным кодом,а статическая с объектным,если со статической более менее понятно,что это связано с компоновкой, то с динамической нет,разве это не выходит,что динамическая библиотека написана по определенную систему или архитектуру?

Comment: Промежуточный код = байт-код = объектный код. раньше код ASM/C собирался в объектники, теперь объектным кодом называют любой промежуточный код. но всё же лучше использовать термин "байт-код"

Comment: dll, exe содержат машинный код. промежуточный код компилируется JIT в машинный код, т. е. C# -> CIL -> Native.

Comment: @return, разве dll/exe это не сборка,содержащая метаданные и промежуточное представление исходного кода,компилирующийся в машинный код при запуске файла,то есть компиляция происходит под систему или архитектуру?

Comment: ДА! именно под систему и архитектуру! в .NET Framwwork в заголовке файла есть спец. поля для CLR, в .NET Core компиляция так же идёт под каждую систему, только там код сам по себе кросс-платформенный, т. е. код на C# .NET Core может компилироваться где угодно (в пределах Windows, MacOS, Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как такового "объектного кода", как отдельный вид кода, не существует. Есть понятие **объектные файлы** - это файлы, получаемые при компиляции кода на С/С++/ASM и других языках с компиляцией в машинный код. Например, для Visual C++ эти файлы имеют расширение [.obj](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-obj-files-as-linker-input?view=vs-2019). Но эти файлы содержат обычный машинный код целевой архитектуры, с единственной разницей, что некоторые адреса функций и переменных в них помечены как неопределенные, и должны позднее заменяться компоновщиком на реальные адреса.

Но в .NET настоящие объектные файлы не применяются. Файлы .netmodule хоть и похожи на них, но все же по структуре радикально отличаются (они представляют из себя почти полноценный PE файл, отличаясь от скомпонованной сборки только отсутствием раздела .assembly в манифесте). Их можно скормить компоновщику Visual C++ (в том числе совместно с настоящими .obj-файлами! Тогда полученная сборка будет **смешанной**, то есть содержащей и CIL-байткод, и машинный код), но это применяется только в особых случаях. При традиционной сборке C#/VB приложений компоновка не используется. На выходе компилятора сразу получается исполняемый файл, содержащий только CIL-байткод.