# Что такое .netmodule и как он связан с управляемым модулем

Tags: c#, модули, manifest

Из CLR via C# я понял, что сборка состоит из управляемых модулей.
Управляемым модулем в .Net представлен .netmodule.

1. Видимо начал путаться, и понимаю, что множество .netmodules составляют единый управляемый модуль, который в свою очередь является сборкой, так ли это?
2. В многофайловых сборках, состоящих из нескольких .netmodule, в одном из моих [вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158411/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment2009543_1158411) был дан ответ, что .netmodule это почти как сборка, но только без манифеста, есть главный .netmodule в котором определен манифест. Главный модуль представлен exe или dll расширением, получается манифест сборки указывает какое должно быть расширение?

Вытекает еще один вопрос, в структуре .netmodule есть PE заголовок, который определяет тип файла, получается там, если можно так сказать, до установки в него манифеста указано, что файл имеет тип .netmodule, а при установке в него манифеста сборки-этот тип меняется на dll или exe?

Comment: Вы что то где то читаете, потом приносите это сюда. Вы хотя бы ссылки прикладывайте, откуда вы все это берете.

Comment: Вы тратите слишком много усилий на изучение того, что слишком мало значит. Учтите, что в .NET Core/.NET 5, например, многофайловые сборки вообще не поддерживаются, и в .NET Framework они использовались редко и главным образом только для одной цели, вынесение локализованных ресурсов (не кода!) в отдельный файл. Советую отложить CLR via C# и почитать вместо этого вот этот раздел документации: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/assembly/ В нем собрано то, что реально нужно знать на современном этапе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.netmodule - это просто расширение по умолчанию для файла, генерируемого компиляторами C#/VB при компиляции с параметром [-target:module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/target-module-compiler-option), или Visual C++ с параметром [/LN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ln-create-msil-module?view=vs-2019). Конечно, любой файл .netmodule является управляемым модулем, но обратное утверждение неверно. Считайте, что это разновидность управляемого модуля.

Файл .netmodule представляет из себя PE-файл с метаданными .NET и, возможно, секцией CIL-кода, но без манифеста сборки, т.е., того что представлено директивой .assembly в выводе ildasm. Условно назовем такой файл **неполный модуль**. Его нельзя загрузить и выполнить, но можно подать на вход специальных утилит, что подробно описано в ответе на вопрос [Можно ли назвать сборку многомодульной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1158500/240512). Само расширение нигде в спецификациях вроде не прописано, то есть теоретически неполному модулю можно присвоить и расширение .dll. Но не факт, что любая утилита обработает его корректно в этом случае.

DLL или EXE файл, получаемый при обычной компиляции, можно в противоположность .netmodule назвать **полным модулем**. Тогда получаем такие возможные конфигурации структуры сборок:

```
Однофайловая сборка:  { [Полный модуль] }

Многофайловая сборка: { [Полный модуль] [Неполный модуль 1] ... [Неполный модуль N]}
```

Comment: Хорошо,просто некоторые,когда говорят о сборках и  не упоминают про CLR и  PE заголовки да и вообще про модули,то есть опуская их,упоминая,когда речь заходит о многофайловых сборках.Говорят,что сборка состоит из манифеста,метаданных,IL-кода и ресурсов(по наличию).

После Вашего ответа и интуиции строится картина,что управляемый модуль это и есть .netmodule, а управляемый модуль с манифестом образуют полный модуль,то есть в теории любой .netmodule можно установить манифест и он примет расширением exe/dll и сможет выполняться?

Comment: И что полный и неполный модули имеют структуру управляемого модуля,описанного у Рихтера,то есть CLR и PE заголовок,метаданные и IL-код присутствуют как в .netmodule так и в фале exe или dll?


П.С вся загвоздка в заголовке PE,он создает такое ощущение,будто он определяет расширение dll или exe, и вытекает отсюда несколько догадок, что в .netmodule нету заголовка PE, а только IL-код и метаданные,или он есть и в нем указано,что расширение данного файла .netmodule,или же что он существует,но игнорируется?

Comment: @n_enrai49 Я же написал, что расширение файла здесь имеет по сути второстепенное значение. Важно что внутри. Превратить неполный модуль в полный конечно можно, link.exe это и сделает, если на вход подать один .netmodule. Только в чем был бы смысл делать это?

Comment: @n_enrai49 В том, что .netmodule имеет PE-заголовок, легко убедиться например с помощью ildasm. Он показывает заголовки. Никакого расширения там не указано и не может быть указано - см. выше.